# Resize Image Application

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, file-upload, web-applications

I'd like to be able to allow a user to select an image from their computer and my program will resize it so that it fits within a certain range. In many social media apps, you have a frame so you can select a part of the image that will become your profile image. I want to do something similar but I don't know where to start. Could anyone give me any assistance in what I should be thinking about or where to look for information. I'm currently learning javascript and php so preferably in those languages

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it on the server in PHP. You can do it on the client, in just Javascript.

Try these out:

```
https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/resizing-images-with-javascript

https://imagekit.io/blog/how-to-resize-image-in-javascript/

https://codesalad.dev/blog/how-to-resize-an-image-in-10-lines-of-javascript-29
```

If you have problems, come back and ask here, showing what you tried and what problems you faced.

Ideally use the "<>" icon to paste in exactly the code you wrote, so we can replicate your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try these